# Cannot enable smartctl Auto Offline Data Collection

Tags: ssd, smartctl, smart, smartmontools

`smartctl --offlineauto=on /dev/sda` [-d TYPE] will not enable Auto Offline Data Collection

as reported by

```
smartctl -c /dev/sda
```

which shows

```
Auto Offline data collection on/off support

Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled
```

no matter how I try to turn it on:

```
smartctl --offlineauto=on /dev/sda

SMART Enable Automatic Offline failed: scsi error badly formed scsi parameters


smartctl --offlineauto=on /dev/sda -d ata

Error SMART Status command failed: Input/output error

SMART Enable Automatic Offline failed: Input/output error


smartctl --offlineauto=on /dev/sda -d sat

SMART Enable Automatic Offline failed: scsi error badly formed scsi parameters


smartctl --offlineauto=on /dev/sda -d sat,12

SMART Enable Automatic Offline failed: scsi error badly formed scsi parameters


smartctl --offlineauto=on /dev/sda -d sat,16

SMART Enable Automatic Offline failed: scsi error badly formed scsi parameters


smartctl --offlineauto=on /dev/sda -d scsi

SCSI device successfully opened
```

The drive is an SSD with Vendor `"ATA       "`.
It is in smartctl's db.
It is in an mdraid.

Asking smartctl how it wants to talk to the device:

```
smartctl --scan

/dev/sda -d scsi # /dev/sda, SCSI device


smartctl --scan-open

/dev/sda -d sat # /dev/sda [SAT], ATA device


smartctl /dev/sda -d test

/dev/sda: Device of type 'scsi' [SCSI] detected

/dev/sda [SAT]: Device open changed type from 'scsi' to 'sat'

/dev/sda [SAT]: Device of type 'sat' [ATA] opened


smartctl -d TYPE /dev/sda
```

where TYPE is one of [ ata | scsi | sat | sat,12 | sat,16 ]

returns

```
TYPE device successfully opened
```

CentOS 7.4.1708 x86_64

smartctl 6.2 2017-02-27 r4394 [x86_64-linux-3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64]

Edit: I found bug report for a similar issue on a similar drive:

"SMART status, attributes and thresholds cannot be read due to scsi error badly formed scsi parameters"

KINGSTON SUV400S37120G: badly formed scsi parameters
https://www.smartmontools.org/ticket/819

Comment: Might be a buggy implementation of SAT in the controller. Do other smartctl actions (-a, tests) work without errors? Is there anything useful regarding the drive in dmesg? What model of the drive is it, how is it connected and to what kind of a controller?

Comment: @TooTea 1) Yes, it may be. I edited the question with a bug report I found
2) Yes, they do; those actions & all others I've run
3) No. There are some in /var/log/messages but none relate to this error
4) KINGSTON SKC100S3120G
5) lsscsi -c
Attached devices:
Host: scsi0 Channel: 00 Target: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: ATA      Model: KINGSTON SKC100S Rev: BBF0
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi1 Channel: 00 Target: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: ATA      Model: KINGSTON SKC100S Rev: BBF0
  Type:   Direct-Access
6) Onboard SATA